# How does $.ajaxError work?

Tags: jquery

I use $.get, $.post, and $.getJSON extensively, so I wanted to see how .ajaxError worked. I tried this...

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, options, error)
{
    console.log(e);
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(options);
    console.log(error);
});
```

and I also tried putting it inside my `$(document).ready().`. And then I disabled my network connection. A slew of errors flew up from the timed `POST`s in AJAX (because they were getting unexpected responses), and the `GET`s were coming back instantaneously (cached), but nothing else appeared in Firebug, as if ajaxError were never being called. What am I doing wrong? I just tried again with no console logs and just `alert('foo')`, and again nothing happened. Lots of errors, but ajaxError never firing.

Comment: Try it on an AJAX request that gets an actual HTTP error response from a server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ajaxError` is triggered when the actual XHR does not receive an HTTP success code from a given response from the server, [as you can see in the jQuery source](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L636). The response codes in that particular function are perceived as "success" codes; anything else is a failure.

jQuery also only branches to the code that triggers `ajaxError` when your XMLHTTPRequest winds up with a `readyState` of 4 (complete with all data received), so I think shutting off your network connection would actually put you in a different XHR condition altogether (possibly a loop of condition 2?). [You can see how jQuery branches in the source, too](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L414).

Basically, it looks if the server doesn't say the request failed and send back a code outside of that range above, you likely won't see `ajaxError` being triggered as, according to jQuery, it hasn't received an error.

Comment: Ahh, so it has to actually get data, and then it looks at the response code to see if there was an HTTP error?

Comment: Yes. It examines the XMLHTTPRequest Object directly.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following sample to work from the jQuery doc.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Sandbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings, exception) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            });

            $('.trigger').click(function () {
                $('.result').load('ajax/thisUrlDoesNotExist.html');
            });

        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's your full page look like?

Comment: Like a thousand lines of hell.

Answer (score 0):

If the ajax call made is cross domain, no ajaxError is triggered on call failure.