# Fire ajaxError on a cross domain $.ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm having trouble getting jQuery's ajaxError global handler firing when I use a $.ajax call (on a cross domain call). Is there any way to get it to fire?

I've included a quick & dirty test (adapted from [So how does $.ajaxError work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141719/so-how-does-ajaxerror-work)) below. Actually, none of the global ajax events fire, even if I explicitly set global to true.If I convert the $.ajax to a $('result').load it works fine, but that's not what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Sandbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings, exception) {
          alert(I broke);
        });

        $('.trigger').click(function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            global: true,
            url: 'http://localhost/error',
            success: function(data){
              alert('ftw');
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read here [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions)

> Some types of Ajax requests, such as
>   JSONP and cross-domain GET requests,
>   do not use XHR; in those cases the
>   XMLHttpRequest and textStatus
>   parameters passed to the callback are
>   undefined.

Better to use **[curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)** for cross domain call

Comment: Argh, it's cos I'm stupid. Didn't read the bit in the global handlers docs that italicly says: "Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global."